# Crawling Text data from multiple links and storing the crawled data in csv file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

**What i have done so far :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Documents\chromedriver")
cursor.execute("select TOP (10) Url from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID DESC ")
data = cursor.fetchall()
result_data = cursor.fetchall()

for link in result_data:
urllink = link.Url
driver.get(urllink)
```

**How i can get the text data for the loop of url and save the url and crawled text data into CSV file**
*I have tried it using the scrapy and beautiful-soup as well.*

As there are multiple no of Url's so can't even get the data using css selector also

Comment: please provide an HTML of source and required output

Comment: @PrakharJhudele -  Every Url has different HTML so can't go through an particular HTML format, I just need to go through the HTML of the page and extract the text data as an required output.

Answer (score 0):

create a dataframe and push all your data into it and when you're done **scraping**. Export it to an csv file its the best approach to save tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below sample code format.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


cursor.execute("select TOP (10) Url from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID DESC ")
result_data = cursor.fetchall()
start_urls = []
for link in result_data:
    start_urls.append(link.Url)


class ToScrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape'
    start_urls = start_urls

    def parse(self, response):

        # Write the code to scrape data, If the URLs are different, use different cases
        # Also add the items to a pandas data frame, dataframe_name.to_csv('path/to/filename.csv') does the work.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't have the exact url , These url's are dynamic in nature, Can't even scrape the data with css selector or id's , How can we extract the text data only present between the<body></body> tags.

Comment: for that scenario, use python-requests and `.text` attribute will give the whole output text. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/